# Missing warning of non-exhaustive match

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Why doesn't the following produce a warning, when `-unchecked` is enabled:

```
object Order {
   sealed trait EntryOption
   case object EmptyEntry extends EntryOption
   trait Entry extends EntryOption

   def isEmpty(a: EntryOption): Boolean = a match {
      case EmptyEntry => true
//    case _: Entry   => false
   }
}
```

It seems I had exactly the [same problem before](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/6568) in the days of Scala 2.8.0, with no sufficient answer.

---

**EDIT**

@Jed It doesn't make sense for me that the warning is only emitted for a non-abstract class `Entry`. Consider the following situation:

```
trait Order {
  sealed trait EntryOption
  case object EmptyEntry extends EntryOption
  abstract sealed class Entry extends EntryOption

  def isEmpty(a: EntryOption): Boolean = a match {
    case EmptyEntry => true
 // case _: Entry   => false
  }
}

trait OrderImpl extends Order {
  final class EntryImpl extends Entry
}
```

The only way to make the warning appear is to have a concrete class `Entry` in `Order`!

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4691

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does complain on trunk:

```
scala> object Order {
     |    sealed trait EntryOption
     |    case object EmptyEntry extends EntryOption
     |    trait Entry extends EntryOption
     | 
     |    def isEmpty( a: EntryOption ) : Boolean = a match {
     |       case EmptyEntry => true
     | //    case _: Entry   => false
     |    }
     | }
<console>:18: warning: match is not exhaustive!
missing combination          Entry

          def isEmpty( a: EntryOption ) : Boolean = a match {
                                                    ^
defined module Order
```

Comment: Ah great, then it was fixed. Now just waiting till 'Early 2012' ;)

Comment: @Sciss Actually, I'm pretty sure Scala 2.10 will come with virtpatmatch, which does not suffer from this problem (or _any_ of the numerous other pattern matching bugs) at all. Granted, it will probably come with a _new_ set of problems! :-)

Comment: Hmmm, now you got me curious -- What is virtpatmatch? (In fact yesterday I needed to add a `@unchecked` in a place which was clearly a false positive)

Comment: @Sciss Right now, the only place where you can look it up is the source code itself. Once Adriaan takes the time to write some document about it, then I'll be able to share that. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Entry is a trait, not a case class.